# How to use uitapGestureRecognizer method before didSelectRowAtIndexpath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer, didselectrowatindexpath

In my project I have to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` in `viewDidLoad`, but if i use it, then the `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` method doesn't work.
I have also done so that "The Tap" method is called in a method and that method is called in `viewDidLoad` but still same problem occurs `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` method doesn't work.

Please tell me how to use that method in `viewDidLoad` so that both will work at the same time without any problems.

```
-(void)searchTap
{

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}
- (void) dismissKeyboard
{

    [mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];

}
```

I want to call this method on  `viewDidLoad`. but when i do `[self searchTap];`
the `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` method stops working.

Comment: add tap gesture to a specific view not self.view if you do so than it is possible that your button and table didselectrow may not respond. Please show some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITapGestureRecognizer breaks UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192480/uitapgesturerecognizer-breaks-uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath)

Comment: but i want tapgesture on self.view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517559/tableview-is-hiding-due-to-a-gesturerecognizer-before-it-can-execute-didselectro

Comment: seems you just need to call the selector dismissKeyboard in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. UITableView have a set of gesture recognizers once it is loaded and those will override the gestures u have defined explicitly. If you have a high end requirement use gesture recognizers with its(table view's) superview or with custom view. Adding gestures which not already included in the UITableview doesn't make sense.

Comment: Instead of adding tap gesture, put a button in that cell, on tap of that button call searchTap method. Once this method completes, didSelectRowAtIndexPath will automatically be called.